# Problem with links on my facebook application tab

Tags: facebook

I have created a application tab with some links. Everything is displayed fine. except for the links to a external page.

I have a few links to my blog and other sites. The links becomes bold and there is this text in brackets

```
<a href='www.example.com/blog'>Blog</a>
```

this shows on the facebook application tab as

```
blog(http://apps.facebook.com/app_name/www.example.com/blog)
```

How i can i fix it.

I appeciate any help

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By adding `http://` to the link urls?..

```
<a href='http://www.example.com/blog'>Blog</a>
```